# Javascript Boolean Confusion

Tags: javascript

fixed the problem, unsure how. Thanks for the replies :)

http://jsfiddle.net/w30cfdqk/

My boolean (`isSame`) is staying true and I don't know why. In this simple game, a ghost will appear when triggered, this part works. except if I leave the "room" and come back it will appear as though the ghost isn't there. The boolean only registers properly in the full code when the ghost is initially trigged in the same room as player. If play attempts to leave, the ghost cannot be relocated, i.e. the boolean wont correspond to the two ints.

```js
releaseGhost();
startTimer();

var isSame = "false";
var ghostLocation;
var mapLocation = 5;

function gameOver() {
    if(isSame === true) {
    gameMessage = "The ghost has killed you. GAME OVER!";
    alert("The ghost has killed you. GAME OVER!");
    document.body.innerHTML = "GAME OVER!";
  } 
} 

//determines if 5 seconds have passed
function moveGhost() {
  ghostLocation = Math.floor(Math.random()*12);
}

function startTimer() {
    if(mapLocation === ghostLocation) {
    isSame = true;
    window.setInterval(gameOver, 5000);
  } else {
    isSame = false;
  }
}

function releaseGhost(){
  ghostLocation = Math.floor(Math.random()*12);
  window.setInterval(moveGhost, 30000);
}

window.setInterval(test, 1000);

function test(){
   mapLocation = Math.floor(Math.random()*12);
    console.log(isSame, mapLocation, ghostLocation);
  }
```

Comment: well in your `startTimer` function you are setting `ghostLocation`  to equal `mapLocation` and then immediately testing to see if they are equal, it is always going to be true because you just set them to the same value

Answer (score 0):

Its a little confusing by your description how and when this boolean is supposed to be set.  However, on my initial view i can see that the IsSame variable has not been declared.

I can only think that as IsSame is not declared as a global variable, it is defaulting to its default value, which is false.

At the top of your code you should declare your variable like so:

```
var isSame = false;
```

Be aware that although it may be possible to use a variable without first declaring it, this is not good practice and will cause issues across difference browsers

Comment: It's in original which was too long to post. I have edited to include this and another suggestions and now it will not evaluate to true. I've been awake for over 24 hours so I'm pretty sure it's something simple I am overlooking.

Comment: Can you provide the original code, without any additions for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this function

```
function startTimer() {
  ghostLocation = mapLocation;
  if(mapLocation === ghostLocation) {
    isSame = true;
    window.setInterval(gameOver, 5000);
  } else {
    isSame = false;
  }
}
```

In the first line you assign the value of `mapLocation` to `ghosLocation`. So the comparison `mapLocation === ghosLocation` is *always* `true` and therefore the line "`isSame = true`" is always run, which assigns the value `true` to `isSame`.

You should rethink your code in this point and you should debug your code.

Comment: Sorry, I added that line to force them to be equal to see if the error was in my functions themselves. When I did that, it always evaluated to true, now that I have edited the code; it will never evaluate to true.